# Error WHen Using Gyms Demo For Luna Lander

Tags: python, openai-gym

when i try to run the following demo code:

```
import gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode='human')
observation, info = env.reset(seed=42, return_info=True)
for _ in range(1000):
   action = policy(observation)  # User-defined policy function
   observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

   if done:
  observation, info = env.reset(return_info=True)
env.close()
```

it returns the error

```
/home/lawrie/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/core.py:329: DeprecationWarning: WARN: Initializing wrapper in old step API which returns one bool instead of two. It is recommended to set `new_step_api=True` to use new step API. This will be the default behaviour in future.
  deprecation(
/home/lawrie/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/step_api_compatibility.py:39: DeprecationWarning: WARN: Initializing environment in old step API which returns one bool instead of two. It is recommended to set `new_step_api=True` to use new step API. This will be the default behaviour in future.
  deprecation(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lawrie/ai.py", line 5, in <module>
    action = policy(observation)  # User-defined policy function
NameError: name 'policy' is not defined
```

Comment: The message seems pretty obvious.  You're calling a function `policy()` which you've never defined.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't working because your policy function is not defined. The comment next to `action = policy(observation)` specifies this. In order for this to work, you need to define a policy.

If you just want the program to run, try this instead:

```py
import gym

env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode="human")
env.action_space.seed(42)

observation, info = env.reset(seed=42, return_info=True)

for _ in range(1000):
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())

    if done:
        observation, info = env.reset(return_info=True)

env.close()
```